# How to make div majority of color grey and the other bottom of color white?

Tags: html, css

What can I do to make the color of the div beneath the button white but the rest of the upper to be #f4f4f4 color. I tried using linear-gradient but there was shading coming when it was transitioning from #f4f4f4 to white color, which I do not want. Can somebody please guide on what approach I should do?

```html
<div style="width: 40%; margin-left: 10%; background-color: #f4f4f4; text-align: center; height: 580px">
    <div style="margin-top: 15%; font-weight: bold; font-size: x-large;">Test</div>
    <div style="font-weight: bold; font-size: medium; margin-top: 5%">Test</div>
    <div>One</div>
    <div style="font-weight: bold; font-size: medium; margin-top: 5%">Test</div>
    <div>Two</div>
    <div style="font-weight: bold; font-size: medium; margin-top: 5%">Test</div>
    <div>Three</div>
    <div style="font-weight: bold; font-size: medium; margin-top: 5%">Test</div>
    <div>Four</div>
    <div style="font-weight: bold; font-size: medium; margin-top: 5%">Test</div>
    <button type="button" style="background-color: #808080; color: white; border: none; margin-top: 10%">Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Post the code that you tried with `linear-gradient`.

Comment: You can stop a linear gradient having grading between colors, but I don't think this helps in this case as you don't know in advance how much vertical space the other elements will take up.

Answer (score 0):

Use `linear-gradient` as in the example below:

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, 
                              red 0%, 
                              red 70%, 
                              blue 70%, 
                              blue 100%);
  
  /* for styling purpose only */
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
```

First you use `to bottom` to have a straight horizontal line and not the default top left to bottom right line.

Next you use `first-color 0%, first-color 80%,` or alternativly the percentage you want to cover with the first color. Followed by the same percentage:  `second-color 80%, second-color 100%`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on exactly what effect you'd like. Here's a couple of suggestions:

If you put the button element in its own div and give that div the margin-top and background white the majority of the main div will remain gray with just the bit behind the button being white. Here's the look you get:
[image]
And here's the snippet:

```html
<div style="overflow: hidden; width: 40%; margin-left: 10%; background-color: #f4f4f4; text-align: center; height: 580px; position: relative;">
    <div style="margin-top: 15%; font-weight: bold; font-size: x-large;">Test</div>
    <div style="font-weight: bold; font-size: medium; margin-top: 5%">Test</div>
    <div>One</div>
    <div style="font-weight: bold; font-size: medium; margin-top: 5%">Test</div>
    <div>Two</div>
    <div style="font-weight: bold; font-size: medium; margin-top: 5%">Test</div>
    <div>Three</div>
    <div style="font-weight: bold; font-size: medium; margin-top: 5%">Test</div>
    <div>Four</div>
    <div style="font-weight: bold; font-size: medium; margin-top: 5%">Test</div>
    <div style="margin-top: 10%; background-color: white;">
      <button type="button" style="background-color: #808080; color: white; border: none;">Button</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want more of the main div to be gray and just the button div to stand out with a white background you could give it a white border. Obviously the sizes can be changed to suit. This is the sort of look you'll get:
[image]
And here is the code, no need to alter the HTML in this case:

```html
<div style="overflow: hidden; width: 40%; margin-left: 10%; background-color: #f4f4f4; text-align: center; height: 580px; position: relative;">
    <div style="margin-top: 15%; font-weight: bold; font-size: x-large;">Test</div>
    <div style="font-weight: bold; font-size: medium; margin-top: 5%">Test</div>
    <div>One</div>
    <div style="font-weight: bold; font-size: medium; margin-top: 5%">Test</div>
    <div>Two</div>
    <div style="font-weight: bold; font-size: medium; margin-top: 5%">Test</div>
    <div>Three</div>
    <div style="font-weight: bold; font-size: medium; margin-top: 5%">Test</div>
    <div>Four</div>
    <div style="font-weight: bold; font-size: medium; margin-top: 5%">Test</div>
    <button type="button" style="background-color: #808080; color: white; margin-top: 10%; border-style: solid; border-color: white; border-width: 1em;">Button</button>
</div>
```